# Is there a way to downgrade my npm version to match the node-hid library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Using node.js, I wanted to create a kiosk application with a RFID Reader attached to the kiosk. In order to access my RFID Reader, I installed the **node-hid** library (https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid). However, when I tried to run the application, an error occured, says:

> Uncaught Exception
>   Error: The module 'D:\Projects\Electron\SelfService\node_modules\node-hid...\build\HID.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js required NODE_MODULE_VERSION 73.

I already updated the library and the node.js version to the latest update, but since the library is kinda old, it doesn't get any more update.

I tried to downgrade the node version, however there aren't any helpful tutorial I can find out there. I know there are many tutorial that explained how to install the older version of node, but I can't simply know what version of node I need from the error message displayed above.

I need to get the device readable by the application. If somehow, it's impossible to use the node-hid library, what is the latest library you recommended to access the RFID Reader from the application?

**Note**: I'm familiar with web development, including Javascript language, but Node.js is a new experience for me. I'll try my best to provide informations regarding my project, but if there are some mistakes with how I described my problem or if I have some difficulties in understanding your answers, please bear with me.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention I'm on Windows 10, the node version I installed is 10.16.3

Comment: You can use nvm to handle node version https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Try this command -
Uninstall the electron first then try below command

sudo npm install --save-dev electron@4.0.0

sudo npm i --save-dev electron-releases@4.0.0

And also try to update chrome

Above is solution be sure minimum using Linux 16.04 with x64 processor and for npm version change see below

For NPM Version Downgrade of Linux/Ubuntu

sudo npm install -g npm@version

example-

sudo npm install -g npm@6.9

For Windows - start command prompt administrator

npm install -g npm@version

example-

npm install -g npm@6.9

Comment: I already downgraded the electron and npm version, but the same error persist. This  error only happen when I loaded some modules like node-hid or serialport.

Comment: Require all dependencies in the main.js file that is run by electron.
Run npm i -D electron-rebuild to add the electron-rebuild package
Remove the node-modules folder with packages-lock.json file also.
Run npm install to install all modules.
Run ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild to rebuild everything
It is very important to run ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild directly after npm install.

Comment: .\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the replies @Gaurav, I'm used to have some difficulties in running the electron-rebuild on Windows' command prompt. One more question if I may, does this method can also be applied to other modules with the same problem?

Comment: When I run `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd`, it shows a long error:
`An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@10.16.3 | win32 | x64
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON...`

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the current node and then re-install the desired node version.

But the best practice will be installing node.js using the `nvm` aka `node version manager`.

Using `nvm` you can easily switch between different `node` version as well as different `npm` version.

> Here's a [quick start](https://medium.com/@bmshamsnahid/node-101-install-and-get-started-with-node-js-8442dea963a4) for installing node using `nvm` in both
>   windows, linux and unix platform.

[NVM Official doc](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md) for unix and linux.

[NVM alternative](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) for windows